# How to use MacPorts' gcc with CreateLibrary?

Tags: mac-os-x, librarylink, ccompilerdriver

**Short version:**  What's the simplest way to use MacPorts' gcc with `CreateLibrary`?

**Long version:**

`CreateLibrary` uses `/usr/bin/gcc` by default on OS X.  I can get it to use `clang` by using the option `"CompilerName" -> "clang++"` or `"CompilerName" -> "c++"` (I'm using C++).

However, I would like to use MacPorts' gcc because it boosts the performance significantly for this particular program I need to compile.  It also supports OpenMP; the system compiler doesn't.  `"CompilerName" -> "g++-mp-5"` tells me that

> CreateLibrary::instl: The compiler installation directive "CompilerInstallation" -> "/usr/bin" does not indicate a usable installation of "GCC"

So I tried `"CompilerInstallation" -> "/opt/local/bin"`, which is the location of `g++-mp-5`.  This results in the same error:

> CreateLibrary::instl: The compiler installation directive "CompilerInstallation" -> "/opt/local/bin" does not indicate a usable installation of "GCC"

Is there a simpler solution than using GenericCCompiler?

Comment: Check the source code for the `CCompilerDriver\`` package. You might be surprised at how simplistic the checks are for whether a compiler is "usable" or not. No doubt one could arrive at some fairly simple modifications to the package to make it work properly.

Comment: I get the impression that a driver has to be created to fully use a particular compiler. As already suggested, look at the other drivers in that directory. Now the next question is, once created, how does one integrate the driver into the system?

Comment: @rcollyer a "driver" just provides the right command line arguments and link libraries. Writing a new one does not seem to be that difficult, although strictly speaking since `CCompilerDriver\`` package is not "supplied as an example" (or so one would suppose), modifying it would contravene the *Mathematica* licence.

Comment: @OleksandrR. yes, and more specifically, it tells ``CCompilerDriver` `` how to interface with the compiler. So, while there isn't an "example" of how to do it, you could learn how by looking at the packages supplied.

Comment: Here's a guess: set ``"Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GCCCompiler`GCCCompiler``, in addition to `"CompilerInstallation"` and `"CompilerName"`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. It looks like the problem is not in the "driver" but in the compiler invocation code: `If[SameQ[False, driver["ValidInstallationQ"][compilerInstallation]] ||
   !TrueQ[driver["ValidInstallationQ"][compilerInstallation, 
    compilerName, targetSystemID]], FAIL-RIGHT-AWAY]`. In so it's necessary for the ValidInstallationQ check to succeed not only with the custom compiler name, but also with the default compiler name, which just doesn't make any sense.  Then there's a line saying `(* TODO do separate validation of compiler installation, name, and target system ID *)`.

Comment: I ended up using the generic compiler driver and hacking around limitations by giving compiler options directly.  I'll write an answer later.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I've looked at that part of the package before (albeit not the Mac/gcc section) and noticed that there are a lot of strange/dead code paths in there. It looks hacked together in a hurry and not fully tested, hence perhaps why it's not as reliable as it ought to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the `GenericCCompiler` driver, as follows:

```
$CCompiler = {
 "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
 "CompilerInstallation" -> "/opt/local/bin", 
 "CompilerName" -> "g++-mp-5", 
 "SystemCompileOptions" -> "-O2 -m64 -fPIC -framework Foundation -framework mathlink"
};
```

The compiler definition should use `"SystemCompileOptions"` instead of `"CompileOptions"` so that the user can set their own custom `"CompileOptions"` when desired.

```
CreateLibrary[{"mylib.cpp"}, "mylib", 
 "IncludeDirectories" -> "/opt/local/include", 
 "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print, "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print, 
 "Language" -> "C++"]
```

It is good to note that the `"Libraries"` and `"SystemLibraries"` options are not usable on OS X because this driver auto-appends `.lib` to any library name, which is incorrect on OS X.