# How-to cast a set of random points on the surface of a cuboid?

Tags: graphics3d, random

I have been able to implement point picking for cylinders and spheres. However, I struggle to implement a solution for a cuboid.

Please see code for point generation on cylinders and spheres below:

**Cylinder:**

```
 Point[Table[{radius*Cos[#1], radius*Sin[#1], #2} &[
    RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}], RandomReal[{p1[[3]], p2[[3]]}]], {expNo}]];
```

**Sphere:**

```
 Point[Table[{Cos[#1] Sqrt[1 - #2^2], Sin[#1] Sqrt[1 - #2^2], #2} &[
    RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}], RandomReal[{-radius, radius}]], {expNo}]];
```

In both cases `{expNo}` denotes a number of points;

How could I do the same for a **Cube**?

I consulted [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubePointPicking.html) on how to do this, but I was unsuccessful in implementation.

Comment: By your two examples, I infer that you want a *uniform* distribution, yes? You know how to generate random points on a rectangle, don't you?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I would be interested in a uniformly distributed set of points. However, I fail at implementation. For rectangle, I would simply generate a set {x,y} in a necessary range?

Comment: That's correct; I will assume you know how to do this in 3D. Now, you need to generate on the faces of a cuboid, so: use `RandomChoice[]` for picking any of the six faces, using the area of each face as the weight (thus, `RandomChoice[{area1, area2, …} -> {1, 2, …}]`). Having picked a face in this manner, use your method of picking points in a rectangle.

Comment: I have struggled to implement this in 3d, thank you for giving me some pointers. I will try again! @J.M.

Comment: As for efficiently generating points on cylinders and spheres: `Append[Normalize[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2]], RandomReal[]]` and `Normalize[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]]`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) (available in *Mathematica* 10.2 or later):

```
c = Cuboid[];
pts = RandomPoint[RegionBoundary[c], 5000];
Graphics3D[Point[pts], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Check the average distance to the centroid

```
Mean[Map[Norm[# - RegionCentroid[c]] &, pts]]

(* 0.640991 *)
```

Comment: nice use of new functionality !

Comment: Should be noted -- this requires V10.2 or later.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you once showed me [how to do this with](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32206/12) the gcc driver (not the generic one, which uses a Windows-specific library syntax).  But I cannot find it anywhere. Do you remember?

Comment: @Szabolcs Probably [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/558403)?

Comment: It should be also noted this method does not allow to use your own pmin and pmax when defining a cuboid.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Not sure I understand. The answer used just `Cuboid[]` which is the same as `Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]` but of course it can also be `Cuboid[pmin, pmax]`.

Comment: @ilian, thank you for your reply! I am considerably new to Mathematica, perhaps, I made a mistake when applying the solution. When I do RandomPoint[RegionBoundary[Cuboid[pmin,pmax]], n] I get an error.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic `Cuboid` requires `pmin` and `pmax` to be true minimum and maximum bounding box coordinates for it, not just opposing corner coordinates. For arbitrary corner coordinates, one can construct the bounding box coodinates and apply them as arguments of `Cuboid` with `Cuboid @@ CoordinateBoundingBox[{pmin, pmax}]`, or with any list of coordinates spanning the bounding box instead of `{pmin, pmax}`.

Answer (score 4):

For people on older versions who cannot use `RandomPoint[]`, here is the method I was alluding to in the comments:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Rule30CA"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            n = 1*^4; (* number of points *)
            pmin = {3, 2, 1}; pmax = {7, 5, 3}; (* cuboid corners *)
            rif = Riffle[#, #] &; (* utility function *)
            areas = Times @@@ Table[Delete[pmax - pmin, k], {k, 3}];
            facs = Table[Drop[{pmin, pmax}, None, {k}], {k, 3}];
            pts = With[{zl = (#1 + I #2) & @@@ #1}, 
                       Insert[Through[{Re, Im}[RandomComplex[zl]]], #2, #3]] & @@@
                  RandomChoice[rif[areas] -> Transpose[{
                               rif[facs], Flatten[Transpose[{pmin, pmax}]],
                               rif[Range[3]]}], n];
            Graphics3D[{{Directive[FaceForm[],
                         EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Red]]], 
                         Cuboid[pmin, pmax]},
                        {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[4], Blue], Point[pts]}},
                       Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: random points on cuboid surface]