# Random points on the Cuboid, and using FindShortestTour

Tags: graphics3d, random

How to plot a random points on the [Cuboid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cuboid.html)?

```
Graphics3D[{Yellow, Opacity[0.3], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 1}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

And how can I use `FindShortestTour` for the given random points on the cuboid?

It's easy to generate random points and use `FindShortestTour` inside cuboid

```
pts = RandomPoint[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 1}], 500];
Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[Medium], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{Line[pts[[FindShortestTour[pts][[2]]]]], 
PointSize[Medium], Blue, Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

but I need to generate random points on the cuboid surface

Comment: So not plot but to generate, and you mean cuboid surface?

Comment: @Kuba   yes, I mean cuboid surface..

Comment: It comes down to finding a distance function on the surface of the cuboid, so it might be a good idea to first ask on math.SE how to define the distance function.

Comment: Use `RegionBoundary` to get the cuboid surface

Comment: @Simon, I think that does it.

Comment: For generating random points on a cuboid's surface, see [this earlier question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97783); however, as C.E. says, you'll need to define what would be the distance of, say, two points on opposing faces of a cuboid.